# how to map through an array inside an array of firebase data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

[This is exactly how the array looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmxLv.png)
[Json data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmxLv.png)

I want to get the images data and render it in my react component. I have tried the map inside a map function but that doesn't work. Please take a look at the above image for the data structure
UPDATE: Please take a look at the new photo

```
tickets.map((ticket) => (
      <div
        key={ticket.id}
        className="col-md-auto col-lg-12"
        id="card-width-min"
        style={{ color: "white" }}
      >
        <Card
          style={{ minWidth: "18rem", margin: "10px" }}
          key={ticket.id}
          bg={this.getRandomColor()}
        >
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title id="font-size-card">{ticket.name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 ">
              <strong>Subject: </strong>
              {ticket.subject}
            </Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 ">
              <strong>Category: </strong>
              {ticket.category}
            </Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 ">
              <strong>Status: </strong>
              {ticket.status}
            </Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>{ticket.details}</Card.Text>

            <Button
              variant="outline-light"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ postId: ticket.id, modal: true })}
            >
              Upload file
            </Button>
            <FileModal
              modal={this.state.modal}
              closeModal={this.closeModal}
              uploadFile={this.uploadFile}
            />
            <ProgressBar
              uploadState={this.state.uploadState}
              percentUploaded={this.state.percentUploaded}
            />
          </Card.Body>
          <Card.Footer>
            <small className="text-muted" id="whiteColor">
              Posted {moment(ticket.timestamp).fromNow()}
            </small>
          </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
      </div>
```

this is my render component. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The images seem to be an Object instead of an array, what you can do is loop through the keys of the images object and get the value of each key.

Looks something like this:

```js
Object.keys(images).forEach(key => images[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

.map will only work for arrays, while you have an array of objects. Once you go into the main array with .map, you need to access the images using an object iterator like Object.entires() on the images object.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `images` value is an `Object`, not an `Array`.
`Object` does not have `map` method.

You can iterate over object using `Object.entries` method:

```
Object.entries(ticket.images).map([key, image] => { 
    // return whatever
});
```

Key would be useful for defining your react component's key property.
If you don't care about the key you can instead use `Object.values` method:

```
Object.values(ticket.images).map(image => {
   // return whatever
})
```

Upd, try:

```
{
    Object.entries(ticket.images).map(([key, image]) => {
        const imageKey = `image-${key}`;

        return (
            <div key={ imageKey }>
                Image key: { key }
            </div>
        );
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow the above steps but wasn't able to render and got errors. Could you write show the code to display the image variable inside the image object? Thanks for replying

Comment: Could you show your code please and the error it's generating.

Comment: I actually tried inserting it in the above code above itself but it doesn't work. The above code I mean the main div class that I have posted as the render component. Could you please tell me how to use your code within that render component?

Comment: I tried the updated code and a parsing error saying JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Comment: It looks like you can't use template literals as a property value. Try now.

Comment: That worked but it gave me the key and not "image" property. How can I access that specifically?

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you so much for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

```
{Object.entries(ticket.images).map(([key, image]) => {
          const imageKey = `image-${key}`;
          console.log(imageKey, image);

          return <div key={imageKey}>File: {image.image}</div>;
        })}
```

This worked for me